# Sometimes i receive the following error : Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado

first I want to emphasize that this code is working in 99% of the times, but every once in a while clients complain for receiving this error. I have the bellow code for passing 2 parameters to a stored procedure. frmSetLoggerTime is a form with a datetimepicker (dtpToDate).
Did anyone came across this issue? I'm using Borland Delphi 7 with SQL Server 2008.

[image]

```
procedure TFormDBManager.ActionSetLoggerTimeExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  frmSetLoggerTime: TfrmSetLoggerTime;
  var
  RecAffected, tmpOleVar:OleVariant;
  cmdObj: _Command;
  ParDataLoggerID, ParUdapteTime :_Parameter;
begin
  tmpOleVar:=OleCtrls.EmptyParam;
  frmSetLoggerTime := TfrmSetLoggerTime.Create(self);
  try
    frmSetLoggerTime.dtpToDate.DateTime := now;
    if frmSetLoggerTime.ShowModal = mrOK then
    begin
      cmdObj := CoCommand.Create;
      cmdObj.Set_ActiveConnection(DBRemoteModule.SLogConnection.ConnectionObject);
      cmdObj.CommandType := adCmdStoredProc;
      cmdObj.CommandText := 'UpdateRebelDateTime';
      ParUdapteTime := cmdObj.CreateParameter('@UdapteTime', adDate,     adParamInput, 3, frmSetLoggerTime.dtpToDate.DateTime);
      cmdObj.Parameters.Append(ParUdapteTime);
      ParDataLoggerID := cmdObj.CreateParameter('@DataLoggerID', adInteger,     adParamInput, 4, QueryLogger.FieldByName('DataLoggerID').AsInteger);
      cmdObj.Parameters.Append(ParDataLoggerID);
      cmdObj.Execute(RecAffected, tmpOleVar, 0);

    end;
  finally
    frmSetLoggerTime.free;
  end;

end;
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateRebelDateTime]  @UpdateDateTime datetime,      @DataLoggerID int
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
  UPDATE tblDataLoggers SET UpdateDateTime = @UpdateDateTime,     UpdateDateTimeDelay = GETUTCDATE()  
  WHERE  DataLoggerID = @DataLoggerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using another parameter name: `@UdapteTime`

Your code:

```
 ParUdapteTime := cmdObj.CreateParameter('@UdapteTime', adDate, adParamInput, 3, frmSetLoggerTime.dtpToDate.DateTime);
```

And it expects:

```
@UpdateDateTime
```

Comment: If this is the case why it's working most of the times?